# Binary file read operations in C?

Tags: c, file, binary

I am trying to read the contents of a binary file as a group of n bytes each time and place them in a character buffer and do some operations on the buffer. For the next iteration I have to read next n bytes from the file and place it in the buffer and so on until the end of the file. I can do the same using getc(fp) with normal text files. But with binary files, getc() is encountering with EOF before the entire contents from the file are read. How can I achieve it with binary file in C?

Comment: Do you want to know for C or for C++? Please remove the inappropriate tag.

Comment: In C, you can take a look at the fread() function

Comment: try fread / fwrite in C. In C++ there's ifstream, with second parameter ios::binary, as far as I remember.

Comment: You should check the result of `fopen` (seems the mode is wrong)

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you post the code you have tried, where you encounter problems, the output you expect to see, and the actual output you are seeing. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: What does your code look like with `getc()`?  It shouldn't give you an early EOF on binary files...

Comment: There is a common error in the use of `getc()` that can result in the appearance of an `EOF` before the actual end of the file. But we can't tell whether you made that error unless you show us your code.

Answer (score 3):

Two things to consider:

First, when opening a binary file for reading with `fopen`, use mode `"rb"`.  This opens the file in binary mode and therefore doesn't give special treatment to certain characters.  Note that on Linux this doesn't matter, but on Windows it does.

Second, be aware that `fgetc` returns a character casted to a `int`.  This allows you to check for `EOF`.  If the result is not `EOF`, it is a character will a value from 0 to 255 (assuming of course `CHAR_BIT` is 8).

Comment: In C, is guaranteed that char is in the range 0-255, that is, is unsigned?

Comment: @AntonioGarrido Yes.  From the man page: *`fgetc()` reads the next character from  stream  and  returns  it  as  an  `unsigned char` cast to an `int`, or `EOF` on end of file or error*

Comment: It should say "converted", not "cast".

Answer (score 1):

In binary files, the process to read from files is usually made by function `fread`.Besides that if you want to iterate the process to the end of file. You can use  `while`

```
while(!feof(fp)) // still not read to the end of file yet
if (fread(buffer, sizeof(...),1,fp)==1) //put single variable to the array[]
....
```

`

.

Answer (score 0):

You can read using fread:

```
size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
```

see [fread](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fread.htm)